# Using messaging apps to transfer binary data

Tags: encoding, base64, telegram

I was wondering if it's possible to transfer arbitrary binary data through messaging apps such as Telegram. I guess the question is if binary data can be transferred through text messages. I read somewhere that this is possible if Base64 binary-to-text encoding is used. Telegram is a platform which is not censored in the country I'm living in. So, if I can relqy binary data through telegram, it can be used to bypass censorship. Does telegram support Base64 encoding? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Try doing some simple base64 encoding offline, paste into Telegram and send it to someone or another phone.

Comment: That's impossible and not necessarily

Comment: @Sean Please elaborate. I've got good reasons for its necessity. Why do you think it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm almost certain that the Base64 encoding can be used to carry binary data on telegram. However, there are limitations on the rate of messages sent on Telegram. Therefore, the idea to use Telegram as a proxy is not achievable since a significantly high number of messages needs to be sent.